# Compare and match results in two two-dimensional arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: vba

I have four loops to populate and compare two two-dimensional arrays then add the results to the first array before writing back to the active worksheet. 
Wondering if anyone has a cleaner alternate or more elegant method? 
It works as is but haven't tested it on large arrays yet!

```
Function lastRow(x As Range, y As Worksheet)

lastRow = y.Cells(Rows.Count, x.Column).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

---

```
Sub arrayMatch()

Dim arr1() As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim rowX As Byte, colX As Byte, aX As Byte

Dim arr1x As Long, arr2y As Long

arr1x = lastRow(Range("A1"), ActiveSheet) 'returns the last row in the column for cell A1
arr2y = lastRow(Range("A1"), Sheets(2)) 'returns the last row in the column for cell A1 on sheet2

ReDim arr1(1 To arr1x, 1 To 4) As Variant 'dynamically sizes arr1 array
ReDim arr2(1 To arr2y, 1 To 2) As Variant 'dynamically sizes arr2 array

For rowX = 1 To arr1x 'arr1x is the last row in the active sheet and the end of array arr1
    For colX = 1 To 3 'only fills array up to 3rd dimension as 4th is reserved for the match results

        arr1(rowX, colX) = Cells(rowX, colX).Value 'set the Cells range to whatever your array is

    Next colX
Next rowX

For rowX = 1 To arr2y 'arr2y is the last row in sheet 2 and the end of array arr2
    For colX = 1 To 2

        arr2(rowX, colX) = Sheets(2).Cells(rowX, colX).Value

    Next colX
Next rowX

For aX = 1 To arr1x
    For rowX = 1 To arr2y
        If arr1(aX, 3) = arr2(rowX, 1) Then
            arr1(aX, 4) = arr2(rowX, 2)
            rowX = arr2y 'helps to exit array earlier when a match is found
        End If
    Next rowX
Next aX

For rowX = 1 To arr1x
    Cells(rowX, 4).Value = arr1(rowX, 4)
Next rowX

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: these are both 2 dimensional arrays.

Comment: I thought that more than 1 dimension would be classed as multi-dimensional? New to the subject area!

Comment: What you call 3rd and 4th dimensions are usually referred to as columns though rows might be more appropriate (because you can only resize the last dimension of an array).  A 3 dimensional array would be Arr(1 to 100,1 to 100, 1 to 100)

Comment: @IainSaunders I recommend watching [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  Even though I've been use the VBA for 15 years now,  I learned a lot from watching the whole 45 episode series.

Comment: @ThomasInzina thank you a lot for the recommendation, I watched the whole tutorial and gained a few new tricks. I think I will follow your example and watch the whole series as well at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a cleaner approach to filling the arrays.

```
Dim arr1, arr2

arr1 = Worksheets(1).Range("C1", Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
ReDim Preserve arr1(UBound(arr1, 1), 1 To 4)

arr2 = Worksheets(1).Range("B1", Worksheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: Thanks, I certainly like the look of the method but would like to keep the usage of the lastRow function intact as the variables that use it are re-used throughout the code and I think it provides some clarity as to what is happening.

Comment: I would use Ubound(arr1,1) instead

Comment: Why did you use Worksheets(1).Range inside the brackets again? Wouldn't this work the same?
`firstArray = Worksheets(1).Range("C1",("A" & firstArrayLastRow))`

Comment: I'm selecting the whole range in a single line.  There is nothing wrong with your way.  I plan on doing a complete review tonight.  Reading through your code it seems like you're only updating a single value.

Comment: This is mainly for a practice run (although it does currently have practical uses) and I would intend to expand on it a lot. Keeping and manipulating everything within an array before writing it back to the worksheet should yield some performance gains over the current method of writing index-match formulas to the worksheet and calculating.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. As you can see in the answer I submitted, I went with your method of filling the arrays as when I refactored the code it seemed the most logical approach. I think this made the biggest difference to my code in the end.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  Let me know if you decide to post the new code.  I usually give a more through review here but have been running short on time.

Comment: I posted an answer to this question for easy reference and opened a new question on the revised code [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141849/writing-a-particular-column-of-a-two-dimension-array-to-a-worksheet "writing a particular column of a 2D array to a worksheet")

Answer (score 4):

Couple notes -

1. Your comments aren't needed. Comments - ["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.
2. It's good practice to indent *all of your code* that way `Labels` will stick out as obvious.
3. Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

---

4. *Variable names* - give your variables meaningful names:

   - `arr1` - this is the first array for comparison, why not describe what it is? Same for `arr2`.
   - What are the `rowX, colX, ax, arr1x, arr2y`? The capitalization isn't consistent - [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

---

5. Creating and populating your arrays. I don't think you need the `lastRow` function. If you do, I'd use `Private Function LastRow(ByVal targetRange as Range) as Long` and just ensure you explicitly pass the range with the sheet qualifier.

If so, you can eliminate some variables as well

```
Dim arr1() As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = x 'target for firstarray
ReDim arr1(1 To lastRow, 1 To 4) As Variant 'dynamically sizes arr1 array
lastRow = x 'target for firstarray
ReDim arr2(1 To lastRow, 1 To 2) As Variant 'dynamically sizes arr2 array
```

As far as reusing the `lastRow` variables, just use `Ubound(targetArray)` instead.

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To UBound(firstArray)
    firstArray(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1)
    firstArray(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2)
    firstArray(i, 3) = Cells(i, 3)
    secondarray(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
    secondarray(i, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 2)
Next i
```

I'm not sure what you're doing here - populating the array? The other answer covers this - just populate it ater you dim it undimensioned.

---

```
For aX = 1 To arr1x
    For rowX = 1 To arr2y
        If arr1(aX, 3) = arr2(rowX, 1) Then
            arr1(aX, 4) = arr2(rowX, 2)
            rowX = arr2y 'helps to exit array earlier when a match is found
        End If
    Next rowX
Next aX
```

resetting `rowX = arr2y` is not the proper way to exit the loop:

```
If arr1(aX, 3) = arr2(rowX, 1) Then
   arr1(aX, 4) = arr2(rowX, 2)
   Exit For
End If
```

Also, why are you using aX as a byte for this? I don't understand that.

You can simplify the loops populating the arrays, combine everything into 1 loop and avoid looping 4 times. That should speed it up a bit. And I would really urge you to get rid of the `arr1x` and `arr2y` in favor or `Ubound`.

Comment: I found your notes the most helpful and immediately actionable, they addressed the core issues in the beginning before running through the code alterations.

Answer (score 4):

Let me clear up a few misconceptions in your code:

> ```
> lastRow(Range("A1"), ActiveSheet) ' returns the last row in the column for cell A1
> ```

This is not quite right... Remember: ActiveSheet is something that can change very easily. In the most cases it's a bad idea to rely on ActiveSheet when you can help it. I assume you always want to get the last row in column 1 for the first Worksheet in your Workbook.

incidentally the next line also includes a misconception that should be fixed with the same idea:

> ```
>  lastRow(Range("A1"), Sheets(2)) ' returns the last row on the column for cell A1 on sheet2.
> ```

It's important to keep in mind that EXCEL supports more than just Worksheets. You cannot rely on `Sheets` to only contain Worksheets. Instead of `Sheets` or `ActiveSheet` you should use the `Worksheets` collection where possible:

```
arr1x = lastRow(Range("A1"), Worksheets(1))
arr2y = lastRow(Range("A1"), Worksheets(2))
```

---

> ```
> For rowX = 1 To arr1x
>     For colX = 1 To 3
>
>         arr1(rowX, colX) = Cells(rowX, colX).Value
>
>     Next colX
> Next rowX
> ```

Two things here: for one I don't like how you have explicit additional newlines around the innermost block. And secondly you implicitly access the ActiveSheet. Cells is a property of Worksheet, and accordingly needs to be called on a Worksheet. Since you don't give one, VBA implicitly goes to the ActiveSheet.

In the same vein, `Range("A1")` refers to the active sheet and `Worksheets(..)` refers to the ActiveWorkbook ... For simplicity I've ignored that in the code I present here, but you may want to not rely on those implicit references. It should be clear how you can do that :)

As mentioned above, relying on ActiveSheet can bite you in the back (especially for long-running macros). Instead you should refer to `Worksheets(1)`. I'd even go so far as to wrap your for-loops in a `With`-Block to reduce allocations:

```
With Worksheets(1)
    For rowX = 1 To arr1x
        For colX = 1 To 3
            arr1(rowX, colX) = .Cells(rowX, colX).Value
        Next colX
    Next rowX
End With
```

The With-block advice also applies for the next nested For-loop.

---

> ```
>         rowX = arr2y 'helps to exit array earlier when a match is found
> ```

This can be written more succinctly with `Exit For` (which also makes the comment redundant)

Comment: I used your suggestions for explicitly referencing the workbook and worksheets I want to use, I realised there would be nothing gained by omitting those references. Additionally thank you for noticing that problem with exiting the for loop, Exit For is definitely a lot clearer and something I need to get familiar with using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered my question, it's been a real eye opener and I feel sure that I am on my way to becoming a better VBA programmer.
Following all the advice given, I have refactored the original code to the below.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
```

---

```
Public Sub arrayMatch()

    Dim firstArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        firstArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    End With
    ReDim Preserve firstArray(UBound(firstArray, 1), 4)

    Dim secondArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        secondArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1".End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    End With

    Dim rowFirstArray As Long
    Dim rowSecondrray As Long
    For rowFirstArray = 1 To UBound(firstArray,1)   
        For rowSecondArray = 1 To UBound(secondArray,1)        
            If firstArray(rowFirstArray, 3) = secondArray(rowSecondArray, 1) Then            
                firstArray(rowFirstArray, 4) = secondArray(rowSecondArray, 2)            
                Exit For     
            End If    
        Next rowSecondArray
    Next rowFirstArray
    Erase secondArray

    For rowFirstArray = 1 To UBound(firstArray, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rowFirstArray, 4).Value = firstArray(rowFirstArray, 4)
    Next rowFirstArray
    Erase firstArray

End Sub
```