# Writing a particular column of a two-dimension array to a worksheet

Tags: array, vba, excel

I had some great feedback on my code previously [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141691/compare-and-match-results-in-two-two-dimensional-arrays-in-excel-vba) and I was hoping that I could get some further help with writing a column of the array to the worksheet.

I have an example here where I write one column of my array to the worksheet with a loop, but I'm wondering if there wouldn't be a more efficient way to do this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub arrayMatch()

    Dim firstArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        firstArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    End With
    ReDim Preserve firstArray(UBound(firstArray, 1), UBound(firstArray, 2) + 1)

    Dim secondArray As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        secondArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    End With

    Dim rowFirstArray As Long
    Dim rowSecondArray As Long
    For rowFirstArray = 1 To UBound(firstArray,1)   
        For rowSecondArray = 1 To UBound(secondArray,1)        
            If firstArray(rowFirstArray, 3) = secondArray(rowSecondArray, 1) Then            
                firstArray(rowFirstArray, 4) = secondArray(rowSecondArray, 2)            
                Exit For     
            End If    
        Next rowSecondArray
    Next rowFirstArray
    Erase secondArray

    For rowFirstArray = 1 To UBound(firstArray, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rowFirstArray, 4).Value = firstArray(rowFirstArray, 4)
    Next rowFirstArray
    Erase firstArray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to write a specific column to the worksheet without a loop but it does involve an additional loop and array within the code itself.
I don't know that this is actually more efficient so if anyone has comments or feedback, I would really appreciate it.

The original section looks like this:

```
    For rowFirstArray = 1 To UBound(firstArray, 1)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rowFirstArray, 4).Value = firstArray(rowFirstArray, 4)
    Next rowFirstArray
    Erase firstArray
```

Now within the code I loop the column of data I want into a new array, which I have given two dimensions to ensure that they adhere to the rows and columns (table) layout for writing to the worksheet:

```
    Dim arrayToPaste As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim arrayToPaste(UBound(firstArray, 1), 1)
    For i = LBound(firstArray, 1) To UBound(firstArray, 1)
        arrayToPaste(i, 1) = firstArray(i, 4)
    Next i
```

This allows me to write the one dimension array as a single column to the worksheet, leaving the rest of the worksheet unaffected:

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(UBound(firstArray, 1), 4)).Value = arrayToPaste
    End With
```

I will be sharing the next revision of my code in another post for review and hopefully to provide help to others facing similar challenges.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use

```
Option Base 1
```

It's completely unneeded, just change your loops to go from `LBound` to `UBound`. Remember, *it's always better to stick with defaults* otherwise you **need to explain why** you're doing it. Much easier -

```
For rowFirstArray = LBound(firstArray, 1) To UBound(firstArray, 1)
```

---

What's this for:

```
Dim previousSetting As Boolean
previousSetting = Application.DisplayAlerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
tempWS.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = previousSetting
```

You're turning it off *no matter what* anyway, there's no reason to store the setting. Why not just put it into an `If` block instead?

```
If Application.DisplayAlerts Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempWS.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else: tempWS.Delete
End If
```

---

I'm not sure what this is doing -

```
ReDim Preserve firstArray(UBound(firstArray, 1), UBound(firstArray, 2) + 1)
```

Usually you need to say `1 to UBound(...)` for a dimension. But, you can't redimension the first dimension in a non- one dimensional array. So I'm not sure what is supposed to happen here.

---

Don't often see the `Erase` method

```
Erase secondArray
```

<s>More commonly you set the array to nothing if you need to clean it up, but</s> usually you won't need to clean it up.

---

Your `With` blocks aren't really needed

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    firstArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
End With
```

Can just be

```
firstArray = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

But I think what you mean is

```
firstArray = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1,1),Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
```

What it's currently doing is

```
Range("A1") to (Rows.Count, 1)
```

The `.End(xlToRight)` isn't doing anything excepting the width of column A.

---

```
Dim rowFirstArray As Long
Dim rowSecondArray As Long
For rowFirstArray = 1 To UBound(firstArray,1)   
    For rowSecondArray = 1 To UBound(secondArray,1)        
        If firstArray(rowFirstArray, 3) = secondArray(rowSecondArray, 1) Then            
            firstArray(rowFirstArray, 4) = secondArray(rowSecondArray, 2)
```

Is only needed if your two arrays are different sizes. Are they different sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the catch on conditionally disabling alerts :)

Comment: After testing out the
`firstArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`
I found this to be more reliable
`firstArray = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").CurrentRegion`

The ReDim is adding a column on the end that I can populate with the for loops results, I'm not sure how I can ReDim an array without referencing the original dimensions?

I may not have needed Erase at all.

Also I used the With blocks to explicitly reference ThisWorkbook as was advised in the previous linked post.

Finally the arrays are indeed different sizes with different layouts.

Comment: An array can't be set to `Nothing` - `Erase` is specifically for clearing arrays. Agreed though, it's quite seldom needed.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks, I guess I've never cleaned up an array. I'll adjust my answer for accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea I had to make it easier:

Instead of looping through the whole array, use a temporary `Worksheet` to copy the entire array, then copy/paste only the column you need. It's pretty quick and painless.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim src As Variant
    src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    Dim dst As Range
    Set dst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("U1")
    ArrayColumnToSheetColumn src, 2, dst
End Sub

Sub ArrayColumnToSheetColumn(ByRef srcArray As Variant, _
                             ByVal colNum As Integer, _
                             ByRef destCell As Range)
    '--- copies the indicated column from the given array
    '    to the column starting at the destination cell
    If colNum > UBound(srcArray, 2) Then
        Debug.Print "ERROR: requested column " & colNum & _
                    " for copy, but the srcArray only has " & _
                    UBound(srcArray, 2) & " columns."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim tempWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set tempWS = thisWB.Sheets.Add

    '--- copy the entire array to a temporary worksheet,
    '    then use Excel to copy just the single column
    '    to the given destination
    tempWS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(srcArray, 1), UBound(srcArray, 2)) = srcArray
    tempWS.Columns(colNum).Copy Destination:=destCell.Resize(UBound(srcArray, 1), 1)

    '--- delete the temporary worksheet
    Dim previousSetting As Boolean
    previousSetting = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempWS.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = previousSetting
End Sub
```

Comment: I like the out of the box thinking, but I feel like in a case where I would write the data I want somewhere else, it would be simpler and perform better if I instead wrote the values I want into a brand new array and pasted that entire array into the area of the worksheet I want to include it. The main reason I don't simply overwrite the entire worksheet with the finished array is that it contains formulas.